# C++ linked list delete members why

Tags: c++, linked-list, bubble-sort

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct student {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int age;
    char gender;
    int level;
    student* next;
};
student* start_ptr = NULL;

void add_node_at_end() {
    student* temp, * temp2;
    temp = new student;
    cout << "Please enter the Name of the student: ";
    cin >> temp->firstName;
    cout << "Please enter the Surname of the student: ";
    cin >> temp->lastName;
    cout << "Please enter the Age of the student: ";
    cin >> temp->age;
    cout << "Please enter the Gender of the student: ";
    cin >> temp->gender;
    cout << "Please enter the Level of the student: ";
    cin >> temp->level;
    cout << endl;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (start_ptr == NULL) {
        start_ptr = temp;
    }
    else {
        temp2 = start_ptr;
        while (temp2->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp2->next = temp;
    }
}

void print_node() {
    student* temp;
    temp = start_ptr;
    cout << "Student Firstname\tStudent Surname\tStudent Age\tStudent Gender\t Student Level \t" << endl;
    if (temp == NULL) cout << "Empty Empty Empty" << endl;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp == NULL) cout << "empty empty empty" << endl;
        cout << temp->firstName << "\t\t\t" << temp->lastName << "\t\t" << temp->age <<"\t\t"<<temp->gender<<"\t\t"<<temp->level;
        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}




void sort_age(int x) {
    student* cur;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < x ; i++) {
        cur = start_ptr;
        for (j = 0; j < x - i - 1; j++) {
            student* p1 = cur;
            student* p2 = p1->next;
            if (p1->age > p2->age) //değişim
            {
                if (p1 == start_ptr) {
                    student* p3 = p2->next;
                    p2->next = p1;
                    p1->next = p3;
                    start_ptr = p2;
                }
                else {
                    
                    student* p3 = p2->next;
                    p2->next = p1;
                    p1->next = p3;
                }
            }
            else {
            cur = cur->next;
            }
            print_node();
            //cout << start_ptr->age <<" " << start_ptr->next->age << " " << start_ptr->next->next->age << " " << start_ptr->next->next->next->age;
        }
    }
    cout << "sorted";
}


int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "n= ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        add_node_at_end();
    }
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    print_node();
    sort_age(n);
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    print_node();
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This my code :
I want it to sort by age, but it deletes 1 element in each for loop.

Enters name, surname, age, gender level and prepares a list. I'm trying to sort this list by age, but there is a problem with a node, it deletes it every time. When the node that I define as p1 changes place, it always depends on the start. I think there is a problem there. Sorry for my english translate :)

Comment: Take out a pen(cil) and some paper, draw a list using boxes and arrows, then trace through your code by hand while updating the drawing.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: C++ has containers that are fully debugged, are very flexible, and very performant.  Why are you spending any effort to create a buggy container instead of using what the language provides?  No need to reinvent the wheel, let alone one that is square shaped.

Comment: Also, carefully follow what happens in your sort routine when `p1` is not `start_ptr`.  The `p2` gets orphaned out of the list.